# Remove strikeout in diff

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, diff

I think strikeout of deleted fragments should be removed in colored diff output (at least when old and new version are displayed separately).

With strikeout:

[image]

Without strikeout:

[image]

I think it's easier to understand what's going on when you look at the second image. It there a chance to change this behaviour?

Comment: True, the strikeouts of the asterisks look like underlines in the screen capture above. But for regular words, such as "andoid_id" and "VALUE" above, I think the strikeout helps. So: I think it's just fine.

Comment: Something like <s>I-</s> doesn't work well too. And there are many edits with whitespace correction, and strikeout of whitespaces looks very confusing.

Comment: I find strikeouts really helpful, *especially* in whitespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find strikeouts helpful because they make it easy to focus on the parts that are still left. Especially in whitespace the color is not enough to help me see indentation differences in code; I like the added visual clues by the strikeout.

I've looked at your example picture and my head wants to see the second example as text *added*, not removed, even though I see the red color. I don't know why that is but I suspect it is because I can see the text clearly and so just reads it as normal text.

Also note that there are a lot of [color blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) people out there. [Green and red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Red.E2.80.93green_color_blindness) are commonly hard to distinguish. From the Wikipedia article:

> Protanopia, deuteranopia, protanomaly, and deuteranomaly are widely
>   common inherited colour blindness that affects a substantial portion
>   of the human population, in which those affected have difficulty with
>   discriminating red and green hues due to the absence of the red or
>   green retinal photoreceptors, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

For the [reasons Emil states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157314) this should be left alone, **however** there is a way you can achieve this affect *yourself* using custom CSS in your browser:

```css
span.diff-delete { text-decoration: none !important }
```

Add this to your custom CSS and apply it to the Stack Overflow domain (and any other SE sites) and it will override the current `text-decoration: line-through` and you won't see the strike-out effect when you browse through the revision histories. :)